# I'm trying to link Android Studio and GitHub, but I don't have a vcs tab

Tags: android-studio

https://velog.io/@kiyoog02/Android-Studio%EC%99%80-GitHub-%EC%97%B0%EB%8F%99

I ran it as linked But there is a problem with implementing the fourth process
In the Git Repository life, click vcs >> Create Git Repository
But there is no vcs tap in my android studio
I want to know if there is a way to get vcs tap to show up in Android studio

Only git tap exists in Android studio and no vcs tap
I'm currently using Windows 11, and I downloaded Android Studio Giraffe

I have the same question, but I can't understand the answer, so I post it again
I want you to give me a detailed answer
I searched stack overflow and google it, but I couldn't find an answer

Comment: View -> Tool windows -> Git

Answer (score 0):

1- Sign up and create a GitHub account in [www.github.com](http://www.github.com).

2- Download git from https://git-scm.com/downloads and install it in your system. (I got an error because I didn't do this step before.)

3- Open the project in android studio and go to File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Git.

4- Click on test button to test "path to Git executables". If successful message is shown everything is ok, else navigate to git.exe from where you installed git and test again.

5- Go to File -> Settings -> Version Control -> GitHub. Enter your email and password used to create GitHub account and click on OK button.

6- Then go to VCS -> Import into Version Control -> Share Project on GitHub. Enter Repository name, Description and click Share button.

7- In the next window check all files inorder to add files for initial commit and click OK.

Also, to commit your project to github after these steps are completed: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-upload-project-on-github-from-android-studio/
I hope your problem is solved. Enjoy your work.

Detailed explanation:

[image]

Open android studio. (If you have an open project, you can say Close Project) Click on the first part of the picture I wrote.

[image]

2. Check that the numbered location is Git. 3. Type the url of your Github repo in the numbered place. 4. You can create a file from your computer in the numbered location and load the project into it. In section 5, you can run your project to process Github by clicking on Clone. If you have any questions, you can write again. I hope I have helped.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still haven't solved it I don't really understand 4소
The test button is clicked and git version is displayed but
vcs tab still does not appear 
I would appreciate it if you could tell me in detail how to test in git.exe
I don't know even if I google it

Comment: Edited the post. If you have any questions, you can write again. I hope I have helped.

Comment: Detailed explanation I didn't have a get project from version control
I don't know what to do I'm sorry

Comment: Among the parts you explained in Detailed planning 
I don't know what to write in url on the third list

Comment: You write the url of the repo you created from Github. When you click on your repo, the url of your repo is written under HTTPS in the (<> Code) section.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We've done level 3
We've done the test button for the 4th I don't know how to test git.exe
As a result of this step, it is impossible to proceed any further because there is no vcs tab again
Thank you for your response and let me know if there's any other way
If not, please point out what is wrong 
I'm a beginner, so please give me a detailed answer

Comment: You are welcome. If I find another way, I will write again under this post in detail.

Comment: Is there any other way?